# When a Windows Store App crashes, is there a way to see why it crashed?

Tags: windows-8

The **Messaging** app was working fine earlier, but now every time I click on the **Messaging** app on the **Start** screen, it opens stays open for about a second, and then weirdly I'm taken back to the **Start** screen. The same thing is happening with the **Calendar** app.

When I take the mouse to the upper left hot corner, the apps that just crashed seem to be listed, but with weird icons.

[image]

Application crashing is not uncommon in Windows, but previous Windows editions provided some sort of error message, however cryptic and unreadable.

I'm guessing those weird icons implies the apps were unable to run or crashed for some reason, but does anyone know where I can see the crash reports?

Comment: Have you looked in the application's directory to see if there is a log file.  Applications have always been responsible for loggging their own problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

Open the Event Viewer and navigate to `Windows Logs -> Application`. It will contain all application logs including errors, warnings and information.

[image: Event Viewer]

Comment: How do you open the event viewer?

Comment: Search it in your start menu- Its the application with the icon that looks like an agenda.